# Rest Easy via html is not working

Tags: java

I have a rest easy url. When i type the url in browser java class get called returns the output. when i call the index.html file it is not loading. i am using tomcat7

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
xmlns="http://java.sun.com    /xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns
/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>projectname</display-name>
<resource-ref>
<description>MySQL Datasource example</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/projectnamedb</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
<context-param>
<param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>${catalina.home}\conf\log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>inputPropertiesLocation</param-name>
<param-value>${catalina.home}\conf\projectDetails.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you please provide whole `web.xml` here with welcome page?

Comment: here edited question with entire web.xml file

Comment: Ok change `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>*</url-pattern>` and `<welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>` to `<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>`. For me it is working fine.

Comment: if i remove this /* from url-pattern i am getting javax.naming.NamingException: No naming context bound to this class loader and tomcat server also not starting. I removed only forward slash

Comment: I said change `/*` to `*`.

Comment: ya i removed only / this i retained * my final code is like this<url-pattern>*</url-pattern>

Comment: Well I am working on `.xhtml` and this `<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>` is working for me. So try this `<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>`

Answer (score 0):

Well 2 things to know here

1) You cannot type simply `http://index.html` you have to give path to the index page like `http://projectname/path/to/index.html`

2) The other simple way is to add `index.html` as welcome page. So when-ever server is started it opens `index.html` page at first. like

```
<welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>path/to/index.html</welcome-file>  
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: my index.html is located in webcontent folder my url is http://localhost:8080/projectname/index.html

Comment: Is there no `WebContent` folder? If yes then place `index.html` into it and add Welcome page like this `<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>`

Comment: My project dynamic web project in eclipse inside the WebContent folder i kept index.html file

Comment: put these lines in `web.xml` `<welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>  
</welcome-file-list>`

Comment: try this `<welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>  
</welcome-file-list>`

Comment: if i comment servlet mapping tag from web.xml file i can able to load index.html But my rest easy url's not working